# altium cannot change hole color

Tags: altium, negative

I am trying to print pdf of negative artwok in the altium.  I am adding full fill on the board different layer. Then change layer color( make black and white ) through Page Setup>Advanced>Preferences. But I cannot color the holes. Some old altium versions have pad hole color and via hole color but I am using Altium Designer 16, where I am unable to find the options.
Question: how to enable the color options for pad holes in Altium?

---

I trying to make negative artwork pdf. Here my result.
[image]

I want to make black holes but it's grey.

Comment: Why bother making the gray holes black? They're just going to be drilled out anyway, it doesn't matter if they have copper on them or not.

Comment: @DerStrom8 - OP said they're trying to make a PDF, I think this is only about creating a visual...

Comment: @Bort Ah, I see

Comment: @DerStrom8 if holes is not black, hole's area will be copper. Its create a problem when try to drill holes.

Comment: @MSB You mean your drill bit can't even drill through a thin layer of copper? Sounds like you need a better drill bit. Anyway, the negative artwork you are showing won't work for a standard etching process -- The parts you want to KEEP should be black, not white. If you invert the colors then you can always touch it up with a black Sharpie (permanent marker)

Comment: @DerStrom8 my drill bit can easly drill copper but non copper area help to drill for exactly right position. And i am not using standart etching.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do and why you want to change their color, but the settings are right in the View Configurations dialog.

[image]

You can open this dialog by clicking the colored box next to the "LS" button at the bottom left of the PCB editor.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way: right click on the corresponding Fabrication Output -> Page Setup -> Color Set -> Mono